# Sending multiple message over a socket in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

I am new to C/C++. I am using the following code to send multiple messages to my server. A CONNECT message, a new line and then a null terminator. But when I send these messages, they are getting converted somewhere. I collected the messages exchanged using Wireshark. Because of the difference in what I am sending and what really got sent to the server, my server doesn't respond well. Please help. Thank you.

**C code (What I am trying to send):**

```
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    char peer0_0[] = {0x43, 0x4f, 0x4e, 0x4e, 0x45, 0x43, 0x54, 0x0d, 0x0a };
    char peer0_1[] = {0x0d, 0x0a }; //NEW LINE
    char peer0_2[] = {0x00, 0x0d, 0x0a }; //NULL TERM

    n = send(sockfd,peer0_0,strlen(peer0_0),0);
    n = send(sockfd,peer0_1,strlen(peer0_1),0);
    n = send(sockfd,peer0_2,strlen(peer0_2),0);
```

**What I see in Wireshark (going to the server):**

```
    char peer0_0[] = {0x43, 0x4f, 0x4e, 0x4e, 0x45, 0x43, 0x54, 0x0d, 0x0a };
    char peer0_1[] = {0x0d, 0x0a, 0xc3, 0x5f, 0xff, 0x7f };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `strlen`, but the arrays are not null terminated. Use `sizeof`:

```
n = send(sockfd,peer0_0,sizeof(peer0_0),0);
n = send(sockfd,peer0_1,sizeof(peer0_1),0);
n = send(sockfd,peer0_2,sizeof(peer0_2),0);
```

`strlen` is no good, as you have null terminator inside the third array (the first byte), so `strlen(peer0_2)` = 0.

Answer (score 1):

strlen returns the correct length of the string only when the last character of the string is '\0' (which is the hex value 0x00). Here, strings are not NULL terminated which result in the garbage values being sent.